# Open .123 Format File

Tags: files, lotus-notes, convert

Does anyone know how to open a .123 file? Apparently this is a Lotus Notes workbook? All we have is Windows Office...

Comment: Is Windows Office more commonly known as Microsoft Office? Does it include Excel?

Comment: That might even predate Lotus Notes. Lotus's original killer app was a spreadsheet called Lotus 123

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a Lotus 123 (spreadsheet) file. I just checked and **OpenOffice** supports *.123 files. So, you can definitely use OpenOffice and import the .123 file and export it to a .xls file. Try using Excel first but if that fails, use OpenOffice.

Answer (score 0):

Excel XP (or was it 2002?) was able to open some very old Lotus spreadsheets for me a couple years ago. Do you have Excel?

Comment: Only have 2007 in the business now.

Comment: What happened when you tried to open the .123 spreadsheet with Excel 2007?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great service for you: [filext.com](http://filext.com/file-extension/123)

It says:

```
Primary association: 1-2-3
Company: IBM
File classification: Spreadsheet
Mime type: application/vnd.lotus-1-2-3, application/x-lotus123, zz-application/zz-winassoc-123
```

So use lotus, or any spreadsheet program.